# Invalid JSON primitive On Post

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I know this question has been asked multiple times in Stakoverflow.But none of the solution is helping me .Can anyone tell me what had been done wrong

I have a Controller Action as below

```
<HttpPost()>
    Function WFUserEdited(ByVal userdetails As userdetails) As ActionResult
            Return View()
    End Function
```

And My Viewmodel is like below

```
Public Class userdetails
    Public Property Username As String
    Public Property Password As String
    Public Property Fullname As String
    Public Property Location As String
    Public Property Appcode As String
    Public Property Userlevel As String
End Class
```

And My Jquery Ajax call is like below

```
 $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                var q = validate();
                if (q = true) {
                    var userdetails = {};
                    userdetails.UserName = $('#txtusername').val().toString();
                    userdetails.Password = $('#txtPassword').val().toString();
                    userdetails.Fullname = $('#txtfullName').val().toString();
                    userdetails.Location = $('#txt_location').val().toString();
                    userdetails.Appcode = $("#drp_appcode").chosen().val().toString();
                    userdetails.Userlevel = $("#drp_userlevel").chosen().val().toString();
                    userdetails = JSON.stringify(userdetails);
                    var url = '@Url.Action("WFUserEdited", "WFUser")';

                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: 'POST',
                        traditional: false,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: { "userdetails": userdetails },
                        success: function (data) {
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

And at The Beginexecutecore iam getting the below exception

```
 Protected Overrides Function BeginExecuteCore(callback As AsyncCallback, state As Object) As IAsyncResult
        Try
            ViewBag.UserImage = "http://_layouts/15/CaptarisWFTasksWebPart/EmployeeImages/sree.jpg"

        Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
            Return MyBase.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state)
        End Try
        Return MyBase.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state)
    End Function
```

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Invalid JSON primitive: userdetails.

Comment: You have already stringified `userdetails` so its just `data: userdetails` (or easier - just delete the `userdetails = JSON.stringify(userdetails);` line and the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` option and just use `data: userdetails` (and your `traditional: false,` is pointless, as are all your `.toString()`)

Comment: can you please put it as answer so that I can accept so that somebody can use it easily..Meanwhile if possible can you please suggest where i can read about these json and stingify +ajax things

Comment: Its working correctly after your corrections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your specify `contentType: "application/json`, you must stringify the data you send as JSON. In your case, the data is a javascript objec` (which contains some stringified data), not JSON.

Since `userdetails` is already stringified (using `JSON.stringify()`), then change the ajax code to

```cs
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: userdetails,
    success: function (data) {
        ...
});
```

However, there is no need to send it as JSON. You can use the default `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`

Delete the `userdetails = JSON.stringify(userdetails);` line of code, and then its just

```cs
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: userdetails,
    success: function (data) {
        ...
});
```

Note in both cases, you can omit the `traditional: false` option.

And if you have generated your form controls correctly using the `HtmlHelper` methods to bind to your model properties, then you do not need to manually create the `object`. You can simply use `.serialize()`. In addition, you should be handling the forms submit event, not the button click event, and checking `.valid()`

```cs
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).valid()) {
        return;
    }
    var userdetails = $(this).serialize();
    var url = '@Url.Action("WFUserEdited", "WFUser")';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: userdetails,
        success: function (data) {
            ...
    });
});
```